# Biztalk Pipeline That Will Disassemble Multiple Flat File Schemas

Tags: biztalk, pipeline, flat-file, disassembly

In my BizTalk Project, I need to have a Receive Pipeline that will disassemble four different flat files that each have a unique schema. That's to say, the pipeline must resolve the schema of the flat file sent through as 1 of 4 flat file schemas dynamically at runtime.

The best approach I have heard to do this is to just have 4 Flat File Disassemble shapes in the Disassemble stage of my pipeline. The logic behind this is that BizTalk will run through the disassemble shapes one by one until it matches the schema of the document to one of the schemas designated in the disassembler components - sort of like an if statement on the schema type. However, no matter which of the 4 documents I pass through, BizTalk seems to always want to go with the very first schema in line in the pipeline disassemble shapes.

So my question(s): Can someone explain in more detail exactly what happens when more than one flat file disassemble shape gets added to a pipeline? Is there a better alternative than to take this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly how the Flat File Disassembler probes the messages is not well documented.  However, it usually doesn't matter because if it doesn't work, well, it just doesn't work in you case.

What you can do is wrap the Flat File Disassembler and implement you own, more robust, detection logic.

Here's an example: http://biztalkxin.blogspot.com/2012/11/biztalk-2010-create-dynamic-flat-file.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you implemented IProbeMessage interface. This interface probe method allows to return true or false based on which pipeline execution goes to next pipeline component